# asio::post with executor, callable and asio::use_future

Tags: c++, asio

In general asio provides an asyncrhonous interface for its classes (like `asio::tcp::socket`), where you have to provide a `CompletionTokenT` which is used to determine how a caller is notified about completion of the asynchronous call.
The return type of the async function is determined at compile time from the `CompletionTokenT` type. It can be `void` for a callable object (lambda passed) or, for example, `std::future` for `asio::use_future`.

```
asioTcpSocket.async_connect(ipAddress, [](const auto& error){}); // void return type
auto future = asioTcpSocket.async_connect(ipAddress, asio::use_future); // specialization for std::future return type
```

However, I can't see a simple way to post a callable to an executor and use `asio::use_future` simultaneously. The documentation has:

```
template<
    typename Executor,
    typename CompletionToken = DEFAULT>
DEDUCED post(
    const Executor & ex,
    CompletionToken && token = DEFAULT,
    typename constraint< execution::is_executor< Executor >::value||is_executor< Executor >::value >::type  = 0);
```

> This function submits an object for execution using the specified executor. The function object is queued for execution, and is never called from the current thread prior to returning from post().

So I can post a lambda, but I can't make it to return a synchronization primitive like `std::future`, because there is no way to pass both the lambda and `asio::use_future`.

I know that I can wrap a promise inside the lambda and return a future, but this is not consistent with the API and Universal Asyncrhonous Model:

```
    struct executor
    {
        asio::any_io_executor executor;

        template<typename T>
        using future_type = std::future<T>;

        template<typename CallableT>
        future_type<void> post(CallableT &&callable) const
        {
            std::promise<void> p{};
            auto future = p.get_future();
            asio::post(executor,
                       [p = std::move(p), callable = std::forward<CallableT>(callable)]() mutable
                       {
                           callable();
                           p.set_value();
                       });
            return future;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Does use_future work?: https://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.19.2/doc/asio/reference/use_future_t/operator_lp__rp_.html, so e.g. asio::post(executor, use_future(callable));

Comment: @JeffGarrett I'll try. But it seems to be what I need

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer, but you can use `asio::async_initiate` to convert the `use_future` token into a handler that can be passed to `asio::post`. See https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/model/completion_tokens.html